# issue GStreamer Pipeline with appsink

Tags: video-streaming, pipeline, gstreamer, rtsp

I am new to use Gstreamer to stream video. my pipeline use appsink element to transmit video. the complete log:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://<username>:<password>@XX.XX.XX.XX/
xxxx.sdp ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! appsink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://DAIFUKU_TEST:DAIFUKU_TEST@10.10.100.84/stream1.sdp
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 1
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
```

how to check whether appsink is connected or not? suggest me any other alternative way to check it and connect with appsink.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.